# How to change date format in Netezza?

Tags: sql, ssis, datetime-format, netezza

I have one datetime field(startdatetime) store in Netezza DB as varchar because SSIS is truncating milisec and I want datetime till milisec.

So now I have startdatetime value is like 2014-1-2 11:23:31.921000000
and I want it 2014-01-02 11:23:31.921 Length should be 23. How can I do that?

So what I am doing is I want to do incremental load so i am getting max(startdatetime) from the table and compare it to startdatetime (datetime data type) field coming from source so when startdatetime > max(startdatetime), load that new data. So for that purpose I need to convert it to like 2014-01-02 11:23:31.921

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking for here. Is startdatetime stored in Netezza as a VARCHAR in all references to columns of that name, or are some timestamps? Are you asking how to compare a VARCHAR representation of a timestanp to an actual timestamp?

Comment: Perhaps some sample DDL would help

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is the to_char function, specifically `to_char(startdatetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS.US')`. See [IBM's documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_conversion_funcs.html).

If that still leaves too many '0' characters on the end, try using the regex functions to replace it.

`regexp_replace(to_char(startdatetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS.US'), '0+$', '')`